# swift variables inspection in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've crawled the whole net but can't find a valid answer.

I have a bridged iOS swift application (cordova plugin) that works but when i set a breakpoint and try to watch an expression in Xcode i always get "Invalid Expression". I can NSLog the value fine though.

I'd like to be able to inspect the variables.

Any idea ? I'm using Xcode 6.1

Here's the problem :

[image]

thanks

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example of what you are experiencing an issue with? Maybe a screenshot? Some context or the ability to attempt to reproduce may help people answer your question.

Comment: thanks, added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LLDB` to inspect you variables, there a several commands you can use in console, while your application is stopped in a breakpoint.
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-command-examples.html) you have a lots of commands.
Type `po enableAutomaticUser` on `LLDB` console to check it or cast it, since `AnyObject` can be anything.